# MySQL calculate the number of row under specific condition : range from A ± 1

Tags: mysql

There's two table in my database:

Table A

```
Column_A1 column_A2
 A1         10
 A2         20
 A3         30
```

Table B

```
Column_B1 column_B2
 B1         11
 B2         21
 B3         31
 B4         29
```

I want to calculate how many row of table B match the following condition:

range:
A1±1,
A2±1,
A3±1,
...

for example:

B1∈[A1-1,A1+1]
count these row, return value 1.

B2∈[A2-1,A2+1]
count these row, return value 1.

B3∈[A3-1,A3+1]
B4∈[A3-1,A3+1]
count these row, return value 2.

Result should be like this:

```
Column_A1 column_A2 num_match
 A1         10        1
 A2         20        1
 A3         30        2
```

It's easy to use a loop to do this in other programming language, but what's the simplest way to make it in MySQL ? Thanks.

Comment: don't spam with irreleant tags

Comment: Do you want to match all values between A1+1 and A1 -1 or just only A1+1 and A1-1?

Comment: all the value between “themselves ± 1” A1 match A1±1, A2 match A2±1 @dsharew

Comment: my question was when you say ```A1±1``` do is it match [A1-1, A, A1+1] or [A1+1, A1-1]? anyways try the answer I gave you and let me know if does not work for you.

Comment: range : [A1-1,A1+1] so the answer might have some change..sorry for not ask the question clearly, I would edit my question.@dsharew

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try like this:

```
SELECT table_a.Column_A1, table_a.Column_A2, count(table_b.Column_B2) as num_match
FROM table_a 
LEFT JOIN (SELECT * FROM table_b) AS table_b
ON table_a.Column_A2 = table_b.Column_B2 - 1 OR table_a.Column_A2 = table_b.Column_B2 + 1;
```